# NullReferenceException Include LINQ expression MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

Following code in a Details.cshtml page:

```
 @{
            @Html.Raw(" | ");
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.Payments.Count; i++)
            {
                @Html.Raw("<a href=../../Payment/Details/" + Model.ID + "/" + Model.Payments.ElementAt(i).accountID + ">" + Model.Payments.ElementAt(i).Account.landIOC + "</a>");           
                @Html.Raw(" | ");
            }
        }
```

Model.Payments.ElementAt(i).Account is always NULL for some reason, although a payment always has exactly one account AND we include Account in our LINQ expression (PaymentController):

```
_erasDb.Payments.Include("Account").Include("Event").Where(...)
```

We have no idea why Account is NULL. For the complete code, see:

http://pastebin.com/Yf1JDsMF

Comment: We're using MVC3 with Razor View Engine

For our database access we have an .edmx with ADO.NET Self-Tracking Entity Generator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple calls to `ElementAt` is pretty inefficient. Just switch to `foreach` - it should fix `ElementAt` returning `null`, be more efficient, and simpler.

Also, why not just:

```
<text> | </text>
foreach(var payment in Model.Payments)
{
    <a href=../../Payment/Details/@Model.ID/@payment.accountID">@payment.Account.landIOC</a>          
    <text> | </text>
}
```

If you are using lots of `@Html.Raw(...)`, you're probably missing a trick... in particular, you stand a good chance of opening xss holes if you use too much `.Raw`.

Comment: You sir, are the saviour of our project :D ♥

Comment: Damn, I cheered too soon... It now works half the time... Very weird.

Comment: @Matthias - are there ever cases where the account itself is null?

Comment: No, Payment has a foreign key to Account and is required, so a payment always has exactly 1 account.

Comment: We've just found the problem... In our event mapper:

var @event = _erasDb.Events
                .Include("BulletinDispatches")
                .Include("BulletinDispatches.Receiver")
                .Include("BulletinDispatches.Receiver.Country")
                .Include("Participations")
                .Include("Sport")
                .Include("Payments")
                .Where(e => e.ID == eventId).FirstOrDefault();

.Where was on a different place, right before Participations...

Answer (score 2):

Questions: what EF scheme are you using db, model  or code first?
in your view you can use `<text> | </text>` to replace Html.Raw(" | ");
Again your link generation strategy is a bit wired. Those links, i suppose, have corresponding actions, so there must be routes and you can use Html.ActionLink.
And iterating with a foreach(var m in Model.Payments) could make your code a bit more prety:

```
@{
 <text> |
  @foreach(var m in Model.Payments){
    <text>
    @Html.ActionLink(m.Account.landIOC,"Details","Account",new{Id = m.ID, AccountId= m.AccountID}) |
    </text>
  }
</text>
}
```

Now this could be a starting point.

Comment: Same problem. NullReferenceException